# How to find a substring/word if it lies at the boundary of bounded buffer

Tags: java

I am reading from an `Inputstream` with a bounded buffer of 200 bytes and I want to find a substring in it. I used the `string.indexOf(substring)`.

But it does not return the right answer if substring crosses the boundary. e.g starts from 199th byte.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, you need to propery handle words spanning the buffer. There is not much around that (besides not using a buffer at all). Consider reading it line by line (if a line is a acceptable word boundary).

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches that I can think of:

1. Normalize the circular buffer (*) before executing `indexOf()`. By "normalize" I mean copy the bytes within the buffer so that the beginning of the buffer is at index 0, and therefore the contents of the buffer are not circular anymore. This will greatly improve the performance of searching through the buffer, but it will incur a performance penalty on the first search that follows a modification of the buffer, because at that moment you will have to first normalize. Since you are only dealing with a 200 byte buffer, the penalty will be negligible, and if you are planning to do multiple searches per buffer modification, the savings might end up being huge.
2. Write your own `indexOf( MyCircularBuffer, String )` method which searches inside your circular buffer for the first character of the string and when found, performs the comparison of the remainder of the string by generating indexes based on the same logic that your circular buffer uses for generating indexes.

<sup>* We are writing software for computers with finite memory, so every single buffer is by definition a bounded buffer, so the term "bounded buffer" does not convey any useful information either with respect to how you are supposed to use it, or with respect to how it is internally structured.  What you are referring to as "Bounded Buffer" is in fact a "Circular Buffer". The term "circular" still gives no hint about its use, but at least it gives a hint about its internal structure.</sup>